# How to communicate between pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router, single-page-application, react-redux

I have a single page application in webview.

I have 3 pages A B and C, A is a list page, B is editing page, C is a sub page of B. Clicking one item of list in A, going to page B, B fetches data from remote server and display the data, when clicking one field of B, going to page C, users can edit in page C then clicking "save" button in page C, then going back to page B.

**The process is like this**:

clicking one item of page A=>

B fetching data from remote server and display=>

clicking one field of B, going to C=>

editing data in C and clicking "save" button=>

going to page B, B displays part of the new data

**My problem**:

C has to use "*browserHistory.goBack()*" to go to B.

B shouldn't fetch data when users go back from C.

B should display data from C.

B don't know if it's from A or C.

Currently I fixed these issue by using a redux state and action. But I think it's not a good solution. What if C is a public page, C shouldn't know existence of B.

Do anyone has a better solution?

Comment: Seems to me that if C is a subpage of B, and C allows for the edition of data belonging to an entity displayed on B, then C should *always* know about the existence of B. Maybe you should provide a use case as well? Just a suggestion. Oh, perhaps the application can go from A to C directly?

Comment: Yes, C would be a public page, so from my opinion, C shouldn't know existence of it's parent page.

Answer (score 0):

The action -> store approach is the way to go. Your pages A, B and C should listen to that store and fetch data if it's not already there when the component mounts.

If C is a public page, when it loads it will try to use the data in the Store, since it's not there, it will fire an action to fetch that data for you and put it in the store. Meanwhile, your "C" page will show the classic "Loading..." message.

Comment: Yes, for C, it can read data from a designated place. but when it finishes saving and go back to its parent place, it should notify its parent page to update the data, it should also tell its parent page not to fetch new data. By now I achieve this by calling an action of parent page. But I think it's not a good solution

Comment: "There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things". -- Phil Karlton. It will be easier to understand if you could share the names of A, B, C :)

Comment: I'm still not getting how if B is the parent of C, then *for some reason* C "shouldn't know" about the existence of B.

Comment: Children shouldn't know about parents. Children can listen/talk to a store (thru actions of course). Parent can listen/talk to a store, and that store can be the same store children and parent talk to. The parent gets 'notified' that the children (or a parent, or a sibling, it doesn't matter) by checking the data in the store. Also, the issue might be that you are using the `back` functionality instead of 'navigating' to the parent, since the state is probably being replayed back to what it was when you were on the parent.

Comment: @EmmanuelFiguerola, maybe C is a public page, for example it's a city list page, I have to use history.back() to go back when a city is selected. I can't use any url parameter to tell B: it's from C, don't refetch data.

Comment: @JorgeObregon, yes you're right, I'm using the back functionality, because I don't want to add a browser history, I have to use browserHistory.goBack()

Comment: @jasonjifly what about popping the state after you navigate to it to get rid of the new entry on the state?